# How insert an array inside another array

Tags: javascript, arrays

Is it possible to insert an array inside another keeping its original array form? I looked on google and didn't find what I wanted, so I'll try here. Should look like this:

```
arr1 = [1, 2 , 3]
arr2 = [4, 5, 6]

console.log(arr3) // [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]
```

Comment: Do you just want a new array with two elements, which are each the original arrays: `var arr3 = [arr1, arr2];` ? Does it matter if the inner arrays are the originals, or copies? (i.e., should `arr3[0][0] = 5;` mutate `arr1` or not, or you don't care?)

Comment: Just the new array.

Answer (score 2):

Create a new array that references your other arrays...

```js
const arr3 = [arr1, arr2];
console.log(arr3);
// [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]
```

Answer (score 2):

Or this one use `array.push()`

```js
let arr1 = [1, 2 , 3]
let arr2 = [4, 5, 6]
let arr3= []
arr3.push(arr1,arr2)
console.log(arr3)
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes its possible like the below way

```js
var arr1 = new Array (1, 2, 3);
var arr2 = new Array (4, 5, 6);
var arr3 = new Array();
arr3[0] = arr1;
arr3[1] = arr2;
console.log(JSON.stringify(arr3))
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, absolutely, it's possible:

```js
const arr1 = [1, 2 , 3]
const arr2 = [4, 5, 6]
const arr3 = []

arr3.push(arr1)
arr3.push(arr2)

console.log(arr3)
```

The new array holds the references to `arr1` and `arr2`. Even if the references to `arr1` and `arr2` become unaccessible, the content of these array will not be garbage collected if `arr3` is accessible.

Answer (score 0):

```js
const arr1 = [1, 2, 3];
const arr2 = [4, 5, 6];
const arr3 = [7, 8, 9];

const concat = (...arrs) => arrs;

console.log(JSON.stringify(concat(arr1, arr2)));
console.log(JSON.stringify(concat(arr1, arr2, arr3)));
```